# why i cannot pass a tuple to a function (which adress is reference in a dict), i have a error message (missing 1 required positionnal agrument)

Tags: python, function, dictionary, tuples

i have the below code : (df_data is a dataframe in this code)

```
def instr_date(df_data,num):
    return df_data.index[-num]

dict_func = {'instr_date' : instr_date,}
dict_arg = {'instr_date' : (df_data_instr,),}
dict_col_func = {'instr_date' : (1,),}

dict_data = {}
for k,v in dict_col_func.items() :
    dict_data[k]=dict_func[k](dict_arg[k]+v)
```

This doesn't work, i have the error message :

```
TypeError: instr_date() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num'
```

I tried:

- `dict_funt[k](df_data,1)` to check if i have an issue with my tuple (so i pass manually a tuple to the dict_func[k]) and it works!
- when i do `(dict_arg[k]+v) == (df_data,1)` the result is "True".

So why i don't have the same behavior with 2 identical tuple ?
Anyone has an idea to help ?

Comment: Your function `instr_date(df_data,num)` takes 2 arguments and in `dict_func[k](dict_arg[k]+v)` which is equivalent to ` instr_date((df_data_instr,)+(1,))` you are adding two tuples which are immutable. You cannot modify tuple in python, if you want to add them use list instead. so `[df_data_instr,]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function wants two arguments, not a tuple containing the two arguments.  But you can expand the tuple in the call.  Change:

```
dict_func[k](dict_arg[k]+v)
```

to:

```
dict_func[k](*(dict_arg[k]+v))
```

This will expand the tuple when forming the argument list in the call.